# Angular 2 - How to reverse firebase list after adding new item

Tags: angular, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm searching for a way to reverse my firebase list in real time.

**for example** : I get this firebase list:

> {apple, orange, banana}; == After reverse => {banana, orange, apple}

And if I add new item **(without refresh the page)**, my list should be like this :

> {apple, orange, banana, other} == reversed => {other, banana, orange, apple}

I used this code to try to reverse the list but there is an error:

```html
    <div *ngFor="let f of fruitsList | reverse async">
```

Also I checked this one but the list didn't reverse

```html
    <div *ngFor="let f of fruitsList | async reverse">
```

I checked this link [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293539/is-it-possible-to-reverse-a-firebase-list ] but not as I want

It's fine when I run the application but when I add any new item the list shown as a picture.

[image: Img for list after adding new item]

Note: FruitList defined as

```js
    Public fruitList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<div *ngFor="let f of fruitsList.reverse() | async ">
```

Thanks,
O

This would work for a simple array. For a FireBaseObservable then you would want to do something like this (taken from here https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/how-to-reverse-an-observable-array-in-angular-angularfire2-firebaselistobservable/) Create a pipe like this

```js
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';    
    @Pipe({
         name: 'reverse'
     })
     export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform {

     transform(value) {

     if (!value) return;
             return value.reverse();
        }
    }
```

and use it like this

```html
    <div *ngFor="let f of fruitsList | async | reverse">
```

Comment: I checked it, there's an error with this comment "...reverse is not a function"

Comment: works for me. What type is fruitsList. I am assuming array...

Comment: its FirebaseListObservable<any[]>