# How to reverse observable list in real time Angular 2

Tags: ionic2

I have a problem when I want to reverse my observable list after adding new item

I used this way to reverse it during first start

```js
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
    name: 'reverse'
    })

    export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform { 
      transform (value) {
        if(!value)return;
        return value.reverse();
      }
    }
```

In HTML

```html
    <div *ngFor="let msg of (msgsList | async) | reverse">
```

But after adding any new item, the list shown as this picture [ [List after adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlfKB.png)  ]

Also I checked this link [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293539/is-it-possible-to-reverse-a-firebase-list ] but same results

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I have exactly the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the same case as me and have the list in server-side and a copy in the angular front-end.
You can use `.push()` to append to the list on the backend but use `.unshift()` on the client-side.

So every time you re-query the list from server you still make use of the  `| reverse` but when you add to the list you `.unshift()` on the frontend list and send the ajax POST to server-side which uses `.push()`.

If you only have client-side app I assume you can only use `.unshift()` and not use the reverse pipe.

How I used it:

Client side:

```
private messageStore = [];
private messageSubject = new Subject();
messages = this.messageSubject.asObservable();

//..

this.messageStore.unshift(newMessage);
this.messageSubject.next(this.messageStore);

//..

<div *ngFor="let message of (webService.messages | async) | reverse">
```

Then ajax Post to server and server does this:

```
messages.push(req.body);
```

And every time you refresh the page or load the entire message list from server you just set that as new client-side list.

```
this.messageStore = response.json();
this.messageSubject.next(this.messageStore);
```