# Angular 2 ngFor - reverse order of output using the index

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-pipe

Trying to learn something about filtering and ordering in Angular 2. I can't seem to find any decent resources and I'm stuck at how to order an ngFor output in reverse order using the index. I have written the the following pipe put it keeps giving me errors that array slice in not a function.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'reverse'
})
export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(arr) {
        var copy = arr.slice();
        return copy.reverse();
    }
}
```

and my ngfor looks like this.

```
<div class="table-row generic" *ngFor="let advert of activeAdverts | reverse let i = index;" [attr.data-index]="i" (click)="viewAd(advert.title)">      
    <div class="table-cell white-text">{{ i+1 }}</div>                    
    <div class="table-cell white-text">{{advert.title}}</div>
    <div class="table-cell green-text">{{advert.advert}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you get errors, please share them in your question.

Comment: do you have syntax errors?

Comment: I guess you need to add `if(!ar) return;` to not get errors when `null` is passed.

Comment: theres definitely items in the array. I get output when I remove the pipe from the ngfor.. the kind of errors I am seeing are slice is not a function or reverse is not a function.

Comment: also more precisely this is the error inline template:13:47 caused by: arr.slice is not a function

Comment: You need a semi-colon after ` | reverse`.

Answer (score 13):

I would add `.slice()` as well

```
*ngFor="let advert of activeAdverts.slice().reverse() let i = index;"
```

Comment: Why to use slice() here? And if we will not do slice() what will happen?

Comment: Reverse() works in place. It means, it will change the original array. Slice without parameters returns a copy of activeAdverts, so original array, in this case, stays unchanged.

Answer (score 12):

For such common use cases, I would suggest you to use reverse pipe from ng-pipes module:
https://github.com/danrevah/ng-pipes#reverse-1

From the DOCS:

*in the controller:*

```
this.items = [1, 2, 3];
```

*in the view:*

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | reverse"> <!-- Array: [3, 2, 1] -->
```

Comment: Wow! it is working, even with the firebase Observable lists!

Answer (score 7):

I think @BhaskerYadav gave the best answer. Changing the original array is a bad idea and his/her idea has no side-effects, performance or otherwise. IMHO it just needs a slight improvement as all that index dereferencing is unreadable at scale.

```
<tr *ngFor="let _ of activeAdverts; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="activeAdverts[activeAdverts.length-i-1] as advert">
    <td>{{advert.p}}</td>
    <td>{{advert.q}}</td>
    ...
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Comment: This worked for me. But, didn't understand what you mean by "index dereferencing is unreadable at scale". Could you please help explain. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. All the examples show just a couple of table cells. But that isn't realistic. What if there were 10, 20? If you had to write `activeAdverts[activeAdverts.length-i-1]` in each, your template would rapidly become unreadable. The `as` keyword of `*ngIf` is underused but great for creating a local variable -- and assigning it with the `*ngIf` expression. So in my example, you only need write the lengthy index dereference once.

Comment: Ahh! Got you. Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: @MarkFlorence what if then I dynamically push activeAdverts?

Answer (score 4):

Using the following method u can reverse the output, but orignal array won't be modified,

```
 <tr *ngFor="let advert of activeAdverts; let i = index" >
           <td>{{activeAdverts[activeAdverts.length-i-1]}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
*ngFor="let item of items.slice().reverse()"
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way I was able to make it work is to just use `activeAdverts.reverse()`.
In your case:

```
<div class="table-row generic" *ngFor="let advert of activeAdverts.reverse() let i = index;" [attr.data-index]="i" (click)="viewAd(advert.title)">      
    <div class="table-cell white-text">{{ i+1 }}</div>                    
    <div class="table-cell white-text">{{advert.title}}</div>
    <div class="table-cell green-text">{{advert.advert}}</div>
</div>
```

[I  found this answer to do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45407950/1773972)

Answer (score 0):

[Lodash reverse](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#reverse) worked for me.

```
import { reverse} from "lodash";

this.cloudMessages = reverse(this.cloudMessages)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the default Angular Reverse method on ngFor

```
<div class="table-row generic" *ngFor="*ngFor="let advert of activeAdverts.slice().reverse() let i = index;" [attr.data-index]="i" (click)="viewAd(advert.title)">     
    <div class="table-cell white-text">{{ i+1 }}</div>                    
    <div class="table-cell white-text">{{advert.title}}</div>
    <div class="table-cell green-text">{{advert.advert}}</div>
</div>
```