# Angular 2 : iterate in reverse direction using ngFor

Tags: angular

Is there a pipe/ syntax that let's you iterate over a collection in reverse order using the ngFor directive ?

Comment: No but it's not too hard to build one yourself

Comment: you can create custom pipe

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35703364/5357459) will help

Comment: Actually i just realized that a pipe is anyway not possible because angular 2 does not allow it with assignable expressions ...

Comment: why don't you simply reverse the array and save it in property and use it with ngFor directive, like *ngFor="let item of reverseArray" ?

Comment: I don't want to do it because I only need to reverse it while displaying the values , but have no further use of the reversed array within the model

Comment: I added an implementation to http://stackoverflow.com/a/35703337/217408 (not actually tested though)

Answer (score 3):

Create custom filter:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'reverse',
  pure: false
})
export class ReversePipe {
  transform(value) {
    return value.slice().reverse();
  }
}
```

Use in your template:

```
<li *ngFor="let row of collection | reverse">
    ...
</li>
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: See comment on Vinays answer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ya correct, then we have to use impure pipe.