# Create local variable in *ngFor

Tags: angular

Is it possible to create local variable in *ngFor? For example:

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users; let myVariable = 0">
```

Comment: There is no way to create local variables.

What's the problem with adding it to the components class?

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to achieve? You can have a local template variable holding the index of the for loop if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: You can't create local variables but you can have indices of your users, like `*ngFor="let user of users; let i = index"`

Answer (score 14):

You can use ng-container with a ngIf to achieve this.

```
<div class="message-list">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <ng-container
      *ngIf="{
        isCurrentUser: message.createdBy.email === currentUser.email
      } as locals"
    >
      <div
        class="message"
        [ngClass]="{ 'message--right-aligned': locals.isCurrentUser }"
      >
        <div>{{ message.text }}</div>
        <div [ngClass]="{ bold: !locals.isCurrentUser }">
          {{ message.createdBy.name }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: neat hack, I like it

Comment: Saved my day, a very clever one.
Passing an object will always be true, so we can declare local variables with "as"
10/10 for you sir

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to create a custom local variable within an `*ngFor`, you can only use [the 8 built-in ones](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables).

You can work around this limitation by creating an array in the component class and referencing it within the template. You didn't specify your use case, so let's imagine that what you want is a counter which increments when the user clicks the `div`.

In your component, you create your `counter` array with its initial values:

```
counter = this.users.map(u => 0);
```

You can reference this within your template, using the index of the `*ngFor` to identify the correct element of the array.

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" (click)="counter[i] = counter[i] + 1">
   User clicked {{counter[i]}} times.
</div>
```

[Working demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cvbyqd).

Answer (score 2):

You can't create local variables. Sometimes you can get the index of the item in the array we are iterating over.
You can do this by adding another variable to our ngFor expression and making it equal to index, like so:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
   {{ i + 1 }} - {{ user.name }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

If you need a variable in your component, you need to create it in component class before use it. For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngfor-example',
  template: `<h4>NgFor</h4>
 <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let user of users">
     {{ variable }} - {{ person.name }}
   </li>
 </ul>`
})
class NgForExampleComponent {
   variable = 0;
}
```

Comment: But in the case of a toggle of sorts, any of the items in the ngFor would set the variable for the entire component. What about if each user had a toggle button for example?