# How to Start with Descending Order in angular

Tags: angularjs

How the Way Start descending order Number Via  {{1+ $index}}

Example 1,2,3,4, to 4,3,2,1

```
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="5%">#</th>

                            <th width="20%">link</th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-ng-repeat="user in post.users  | orderBy : '-id'">
                            <th>{{1+$index}}</th>

                            <td> 
                            <a href="{{user.email}}" target="_blank">{{user.email}}</a>
                             </td>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you be more specific? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: just giving a serial number in table without relation to database sorting . Need to start with descending 4,3,2,1

Comment: Give more code please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invert Angular 2 \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703258/invert-angular-2-ngfor)

Answer (score 0):

to do this you can use java script reverse() function.store that reversed array in a array variable  and iterate in your  html file if you are using angular 2 or above.