# Angular 2: Iterating over an array of objects and printing "Yes" to the view ONCE if any of the iterated objects return "true" for the check

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a situation in my Angular 2 app where I am iterating over an array of objects, and if the "completed" property is set to `false` for any of those objects, I want to print to the view 'Yes', because there is (at least) one object with "completed" equal to `false` -- meaning it's still an active flag.

However, right now, the template code I have is printing 'Yes' to the view for EACH time one of these objects with the "completed" property set to `false` returns `true`. How can I adjust this code so that I'm only getting "Yes" printed once if ANY ONE (or more) of the objects in the array being iterated over has that "completed" property set to true?

Here's my code:

```
<td *ngFor="let flag of service.flags">
     <ng-template *ngIf="flag?.completed === false"> 
        <span class="standard-flag">Yes</span>
     </ng-template> 
</td>
```

I also tried using the ternary operator, but it gives me the same result:

```
<td *ngFor="let flag of service.flags">
     <ng-template *ngIf="flag?.completed === false ? true : false""> 
        <span class="standard-flag">Yes</span>
     </ng-template> 
</td>
```

While I would normally handle the logic in the component, I'm thinking there must be a way, perhaps with indexing, that I could this in the view on this occasion.

Comment: I would do the iteration within the component.ts file and then set a variable (`this.completed`) to true when any of them returns true. Then, within the template, you can assign an attribute to show "yes": `[hidden] = "completed"` on a DOM element: `<h1 [hidden] = "completed">Yes</h1>`.

Comment: I agree, and normally I would do this in the component and print to the view the result. However in this particular case (for reasons I don't want to go into) I'd rather handle it in the view directly. I'm thinking there must be a way to do this with indexing of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `ngFor` to make this work. `ngFor` repeats for every element in your array, that's why you see a bunch `Yes`'s

Use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which **returns true immediately** if **at least** one of the elements in the array returns true, so it is the right tool for the job here

```
<td>
    <span *ngIf="service.flags.some(flag => flag.completed === false) === true">
        Yes
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Sounds promising. Will give it a try. I didn't realize I could essentially iterate over all of the objects in the array without using *ngFor.

Comment: Getting an error:
zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 42 in [service.flags.some(flag => flag.completed === false) === true]

Comment: Sounds strange, try refactoring this `service.flags.some(flag => flag.completed === false) === true` into a function and call the function inside `ngIf` instead

Comment: Yup, that would probably work. But in this case I'm trying to handle this logic in the view specifically.

Comment: Then try removing `=== true` and see if it rids of the error

Comment: I had the same thought. Still produces the error. Seems like there should be a way to get this to work though.

Comment: I wouldn't want to insert long logic inside the view if I were you

Comment: We've written large Angular apps, and all of our bindings are really simple, the logic for the bindings such as `ngIf` is inside the controller class always

Comment: It occurs to me that what I could do here is handle this logic in a custom pipe, and use that in the template view. Will give that a try. Thanks for the Array.some() tip. Good to know.

Comment: Please no, pipes are used for formatting data for presentation(e.g capitalizing, formatting datetime, etc), doesn't make sense to use pipe here

Comment: Rather than getting into why it's not workable to handle the logic in the component for me in this particular instance (when normally I would), a pipe is the next best thing, considering the binding syntax in Angular 2 prevents me from doing this in the view itself. I found other examples of the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986017/can-you-use-array-filter-in-an-angular-binding

Comment: Yeah, just do as you please, it is your code, but I think adding a function to your component class is much easier and less an overkill for what you are trying to achieve. Just an opinion