# Angular2 sorting array for displaying in *ngFor in html

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looping through all the posts

```
<li *ngFor="let post of posts">
```

When displaying the date for each post I do:

```
{{post.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
```

What I want to do is display all the posts in order of newest first.

I have tried using a pipe like:

```
<li *ngFor="let post of posts | order-by-pipe">
```

---

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'order-by-pipe'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform{

 transform(array: Array<string>, args: string): Array<string> {

  if(!array || array === undefined || array.length === 0) return null;

    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a.date < b.date) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a.date > b.date) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }

}
```

But it does not work. I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
[ERROR ->]*ngFor="let post of posts | order-by-pipe">
```

Any help would be welcome, thanks

Comment: This seems misleading, where is `toUpperCase` being called? Not anywhere in what you've posted.

Comment: I know, the error does not give much help, this is why I think maybe the pipe is causing it. without the pipe then I get no error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use `order-by-pipe` as the selector it is attempting to find the variables `order` `by` and `pipe` and do who knows what with them.

Changing the `name:` in your pipe to `orderByPipe` resolves the issue.

That was weird.

Here's a demo of the same code, different name: http://plnkr.co/edit/BXkrPqeMYuJMhkx94i6M?p=preview

Answer (score 10):

The Angular team recommends against using pipes for sorting in Angular 2, and dropped this feature from AngularJS purposely.  As detailed on https://angular.io/guide/pipes:

> Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they perform poorly and
>   prevent aggressive minification... Filtering and especially sorting
>   are expensive operations. The user experience can degrade severely for
>   even moderate-sized lists when Angular calls these pipe methods many
>   times per second. filter and orderBy have often been abused in
>   AngularJS apps, leading to complaints that Angular itself is slow...
>   The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly
>   recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component
>   itself.

See a similar discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43092380/3211269