# Sort item list by earliest collection dateTime in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to angular2 and I'm trying to sort out my food order list by collection time datestamp coming from the database.

let say the order object is below and in my template I want to sort it with earliest `collectiontime` in the example below it would be `id: 2454`

```
var awaitingPicking = [
  {
   "id": "2452",
   "OrderLineGroups": [
     {
       "CollectionDetails": {
         "CollectionFrom": "2017-03-21T11:00:00.317"
       }
     }
   ]
  },
{
   "id": "2454",
   "OrderLineGroups": [
     {
       "CollectionDetails": {
         "CollectionFrom": "2017-03-21T11:00:00.317"
       }
     }
   ]
  }
 ]
```

Image shows how my list is being rendered in my HTML and it puts `id: 2454` at the bottom when it should be before `id: 2452`.

**Edit --**

```
this.awaitingPicking.push(element); // these holds all order objects
this.awaitingPicking.map(e => {
  this.getCollectionFrom = e.CollectionFrom = e.OrderLineGroups[0].CollectionDetails.CollectionFrom
   return e
})
```

Template --

```
<div *ngFor="let prepare of awaitingPicking | orderBy: '+getCollectionFrom'" id="prepareOrder"> </div>
```

How can I sort the list with earliest collectionFrom?

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1lXa.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 sort and filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882013/angular-2-sort-and-filter)

Comment: I've updated my question and tried this plnkr from the link you include https://plnkr.co/edit/DU6pxr?p=preview but it didn't sort out by collectionFrom

Comment: I don't see collectionFrom anywhere in your plunkr, and it is sorting by the date field you supplied.

Comment: the `var` is only an example but it would have the same value anyways, but the real object porperty is "CollectionFrom" but that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @robertotomás I've edited my sample `var` object to map out the actual `CollectionFrom` property

Comment: @kram please update your plunkr

Comment: this https://plnkr.co/edit/DHLVc0?p=preview works but its sorting it my date, need to sort it by time like (11:00am)

Comment: @kram wow, that is ugly. stop making such a mess and just edit the plunkr you had before, to contain a minimum expample. The second one has a ton of other crap you dont care about but still not the data that you actually want to use. Focus! :)

Comment: @robertotomás those aren't my plnkr, that's from the link SilentW provided as he marked it as duplicate. Read my comment after his!

Comment: @kram - well, you said it *almost* works for your data, and we shouldn't have to guess what the code looks like you should provide it. So move a sample of your data in place of the sample data in the first [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DU6pxr?p=preview), and get it as close to working as you can, and then save the plunkr as your own and post the new link here. Once you have a plunkr of your problem I will look at it.

Comment: @robertotomás looks like its not working for my case, the sample was using `new Date()` where as mine is a date `string` https://plnkr.co/edit/TYXh2iCDseJNnT0DwKA7?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution uses a custom filter that only goes one level deep, so your data must also be only 1 level deep:

https://plnkr.co/edit/rCGc2IZECuPiL3QqNnlJ?p=preview (updated)

changes:

#### app.ts

```
//...
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  pipes: [DatePipe, ArraySortPipe],
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#item of sortableArray | arraySort:'+CollectionFrom'">{{item.id}} {{item.CollectionFrom}}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
  directives: []
})
//...
export class App {

  inputArray: Array<any> = [
      {
     "id": "2452",
     "OrderLineGroups": [
       {
         "CollectionDetails": {
           "CollectionFrom": "2017-03-21T11:40:00.317"
         }
       }
     ]
    },
  {
     "id": "2454",
     "OrderLineGroups": [
       {
         "CollectionDetails": {
           "CollectionFrom": "2017-03-21T11:00:00.317"
         }
       }
     ]
    }
  ]

  sortableArray: Array<any> = this.inputArray.map(e => {
    e.CollectionFrom = e.OrderLineGroups[0].CollectionDetails.CollectionFrom
    return e
  })

  constructor() {}
}

//...
```

Comment: Your change didn't make `id: 2454` to be the first in the list. Early collection time should be first `2017-03-21T11:00:00.317`

Comment: @kram I don't think you understood the solution they wrote! I blanked too, my first instinct was to just remove the sort modifier :) I've changed the plunkr and code above to give the output you want. You have to change the template from a -CollectionFrom (descending) to a +CollectionFrom (ascending) sort order: `<li *ngFor="#item of sortableArray | arraySort:'+CollectionFrom'">{{item.id}} {{item.CollectionFrom}}</li>`. the answer is updated

Comment: can you check my edit in my question, isn't that similar to yours? if so, somehow mine its not sorting out.

Comment: @kram please show the console.log of awaitpicking after the map. This part `this.getCollectionFrom = e.CollectionFrom = e` is redundant but seems fine

Comment: why did you do `sortableArray: Array<any> = this.inputArray`? Can you explain that bit please.

Comment: @kram sure. I assumed you might not want to alter your original array, so I made a copy and altered it (the full statement is `this.inputArray.map(...`)