# Grab input value and insert it into *ngFor directive?

Tags: html, angular, select, input, radio-button

*I'm still new to Angular/JS...* I'm displaying a bunch of data through filter pipe, and I now want the ability to toggle how my data is ordered: ascending or descending. I have an "orderBy" pipe that is working perfectly, but I currently have to hardcode the direction, and I want it to be dynamic. I want to achieve this via two radio buttons, but I'm having trouble grabbing the input value and inserting it into my *ngFor directive.

```
<input type="radio" value="+"> Ascending<br>
<input type="radio" value="-"> Descending<br>
```

I need to grab the "+" or "-" and insert it just before the "recordStartDate."

```
<li (click)="showArtist(item);"
    *ngFor="let item of artists | search: field1Filter | orderBy:
    ['recordStartDate']">
</li>
```

['**-**recordStartDate'] results in descending order, and ['**+**recordStartDate'] (or no sign at all) produces ascending.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

I'm using this pipe here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35635370/8201772 and there's a demo of it here: http://fuelinteractive.github.io/fuel-ui/#/pipe/orderby. Notice that on the demo there're select options which control whether the data is sorted in ascending or descending order via "+" and "-". How can I replicate these select option functionality? I'd comment on the original answer, but I need 50+ reputation to do so. Thanks!

**Edit two:**

Okay, so I've updated the two radio-buttons as seen below:

```
<input type="radio" name="orderbydescending" [(ngModel)]="orderbydescending" value="['+recordStartDate']">Ascending<br>
<input type="radio" name="orderbydescending" [(ngModel)]="orderbydescending" value="['-recordStartDate']">Descending
```

and use the following in my view:

```
*ngFor="let item of artists | search: field1Filter | orderBy : orderbydescending"
```

then I get the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Himx7.jpg.

If I remove the " [' " and " '] " the values of the radio buttons then the pipe stops working correctly (and I still get the same error).

Any ideas? Again, hardcoding this works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually use a boolean value to test which direction to filter

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="orderbydescending"  name="orderbydescending" value="false">Ascending<br>
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="orderbydescending"  name="orderbydescending" value="true">Descending
```

Then in your view:

```
<li (click)="showArtist(item);" *ngFor="let item of artists | search: field1Filter | orderBy : orderbydescending">
    {{ data goes here }}
</li>
```

Then your filter would accept the orderbydescending value as a parameter:

```
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any[], args?: any): any[] {
        // args holds true if ordering by descending, otherwise, you are ordering ascending
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, birwin! This would normally be perfect, but, I can't seem to get this working with the specific pipe that I'm using. I'm using this pipe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882013/angular-2-sort-and-filter/35635370#35635370 -- there's a demo of it here: http://fuelinteractive.github.io/fuel-ui/#/pipe/orderby. On the demo, check out the select options and how users can toggle between ascending and descending order by controlling the "+" or "-". Any idea of how this works?

Comment: When you step through the code, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: Check out my **edit two** for my update and resulting error. Thanks! Perhaps I'm making a very simple/dumb mistake?

Comment: @Boosman OrderBy pipe creator here. Just change your values to be strings by removing the brackets and `'`. So just `value="recordStartDate"` and `value="-recordStartDate"`. The array brackets are there to allow the ability to sort on multiple properties

Comment: @CoryShaw, THANK YOU!! However, it turns out that my actual problem is that the pipe is not totally sorting the data correctly. My "recordStateDate" values are dates in the following format: YYYYMMDD (no dashes; it's not being displayed anywhere). The pipe is returning 19990505 as a lower number than 19920918. I only have about five entries of dummy data at the moment, but everything else is getting sorted correctly. Those two "dates," however, are switched. Ideas?

Comment: I realized what the problem is: the pipe is sorting my JSON objects based on the order in which they appear in my JSON file. Seems like I'm not accurately indicating the `artist.recordStartDate` key/value pair. Any ideas for this?

Comment: Okay. Got it working. Not exactly sure what the problem was, to be honest. I started working on other aspects of the app and now it's functioning properly. Now I just need to get one of the radio buttons checked by default....

Comment: Sounds like your YYYMMDD was sorting as a string instead of a number. Glad you got it working!