# how to sort list with last name in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I make a list of item in angular 2 .I want to sort that list using `custom fliter` or using `pipe` .can we sort my list with `lastname` .I tried like this

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of userList | lastname" class="userlist">
  <li>
    <span>{{user.name}}</span>
    <span>{{user.lastname}}</span>
    <span>{{user.age}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

but it gives me error so reverted 
please suggest a way to sort that 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdxser?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You have to add a logic to sort the array ,inside the **transform** method in your pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how the Pipe should look (from your link)

**lastname.pipe.ts:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'lastname'
})
export class LastnamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: any[]): any[] {
    return values.sort((a, b) => a.lastname.localeCompare(b.lastname));
  }
}
```

if you want it the other way arround add a `.reverse();` to the return statements or do `b.lastname.localeCompare(a.lastname)`

Answer (score 0):

Add following sort pipe in your project. The following pipe is generic, you can change the attribute to sort as well ex. **sort.pipe.ts**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: "sortBy"})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: Array<any>, args: any): Array<any> {
        console.log("arra", array, '-- args:', args);
        if (array !== undefined) {
            let keys, order;
            if(typeof args == 'string'){ // use default sort criteria
                keys = [args];
                order = 1;
            }

            if(keys.length > 0){
                array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                    if (a[keys[0]] < b[keys[0]]) {
                        return -1 * order;
                    } else if (a[keys[0]] > b[keys[0]]) {
                        return 1 * order;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Declare s rot pipe in pipeModule like: **pipes.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {SortPipe} from './sort.pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [SortPipe],
    exports: [SortPipe],
})

export class PipesModule {
    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: PipesModule,
            providers: [],
        };
    }
}
```

Inject PipeModule in app.module.ts. And HTML will be:

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of userList | sortBy :'lastname'" class="userlist">
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a custom pipe for that.

Check out this answer from Cory Shaw - [angular-2-sort-and-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882013/angular-2-sort-and-filter)