# Implement custom search relevancy using an Angular pipe

Tags: angular, pipe, angular-pipe

I currently have a basic course search feature with a custom pipe filter, [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-bszsae?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcourse-filter.pipe.ts).  It returns results based on whether there exists a match in the `course title`, `description` or `keywords`, but it returns the courses in some arbitrary order.  I'd like to modify the pipe to return more relevant results first, with the precedence being that the search query matched in 1. the title, 2. the description, 3. the keywords.

Some test case examples:

1. The query `"chinese"` currently returns `"1 French"` before `"1X Chinese"` because there's a match in the keywords to `"chinese"` for `"1 French"`.
2. the query `"linear algebra"` returns `54 Math` first before `89A statistics`, even though the latter has a match in all 3 fields.

What would be the best way to go about implementing this?  I'm currently looking at [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35635370/6521206), which would mean I could try to define my own comparator with the following logic (in pseudocode)

```
orderByComparator(a:Course, b:Course):number{
    if(searchRelevancy(a) < searchRelevancy(b)) return -1;
    else if(searchRelevancy(a) > searchRelevancy(b)) return 1;
    else return 0;
  }
```

where `searchRelevancy` could be a function that calculates the rank of each course based on the query

```
searchRelevancy(course: Course, query: string): number{
   var rank: number;
   if(course.course_title.toUpperCase().includes(query)) rank += 5;
   if(course.description.toUpperCase().includes(query)) rank += 3;
   if(course.keywords.toUpperCase().includes(query)) rank += 1;
return rank
}
```

and the view would include

```
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses | courseFilter: searchText |
 orderBy: ['title', 'description', ''keywords]">
```

However, I'm relatively new to Angular and the implementation details were beyond what I can currently follow.  Is this the most straightforward approach?  If I know I'm only filtering course objects, is it possible to modify the current course-filter pipe without defining a second orderBy pipe?

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first want to add the rank to each Course and then order by that. i.e.

```
addRank(a: Course, query: string): number{

    var rank: number;
    if(course.course_title.toUpperCase().includes(query)) rank += 5;
    if(course.description.toUpperCase().includes(query)) rank += 3;
    if(course.keywords.toUpperCase().includes(query)) rank += 1;
    course.rank = rank
```

Then order by that rank in descending order:

```xml
<li *ngFor="let course of courses | addRank: searchText | orderBy: '-rank'">
```

**However, Angular (unlike AngularJs/Angular 1) does not provide orderBy, or filter, and they suggest that you do these yourself in the component, rather than using pipes:**

> Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists.
>   Developers familiar with AngularJS know these as filter and orderBy.
>   There are no equivalents in Angular.
>
> This isn't an oversight. Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they
>   perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification.

Ref: [AngularPipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Taking heed of this, you'd then likely use a separate courseResults list that is a filtered and ordered version of the courses array. You might initialise this to courses before you've entered any search/filter criteria of course. And you might also look at minimizing unnecessary search/filter calls by adding a [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-and-debounce) to your search input (if you're doing it as you type; if you're doing it on a button click then you'd skip that).

***Simple Solution:***

So, building on from your StackBlitz, I got rid of using the pipes altogether, making a new [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-vnjhq9):

```xml
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='searchText' placeholder=" Search a Topic, Subject, or a Course!" (keyup)="search($event)">
```

Where we don't display all courses, but courseResults...:

```xml
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courseResults">
```

... which is initialised to either empty or all courses (as here):

```js
public courseResults: Course[] = this.courses;
```

And then the search can be:

```js
search($event) {
  this.courseResults = this.sortByRank(this.rankAndFilter(this.courses, this.searchText.toUpperCase()));
}

private rankAndFilter(courses: Course[], query: string) {
  var result = [];
  var rank: number;

  for (let course of courses) {
    rank = 0;
    if(course.course_title.toUpperCase().includes(query)) {rank += 5};
    if(course.description.toUpperCase().includes(query)) {rank += 3};
    if(course.keywords.toUpperCase().includes(query)) {rank += 1};
    course.rank = rank;
    if (rank > 0) result.push(course);
  }      
  return result;
}

private sortByRank(courses: Course[]) {
  return courses.sort(function(a:Course,b:Course){
    return b.rank - a.rank;
  });
}
```

***Extended Solution:***

[Edit] A new [forked StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-jqok8a) that uses debounce (so doesn't do the whole filter and sort on each and every keystroke if the user is typing really fast) and distinctUntilChanged (if user backspaces a character, it won't bother), and created a global extension to Array (sortBy and sortByDesc).

So now we have the input:

```xml
<input type='text' #searchInput placeholder=" Search a Topic, Subject, or a Course!">
```

Then get that ViewChild as an ElementRef:

```js
@ViewChild('searchInput') searchInputRef: ElementRef;
```

And then after init, we set up the observable on input on the native element and subscribe to it:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  var subscription = fromEvent(this.searchInputRef.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
    map((e: KeyboardEvent) => (<HTMLInputElement>e.target).value),
    debounceTime(400),
    distinctUntilChanged()
    //switchMap(() => this.performSearch())
  );
  subscription.subscribe(data => {
    this.performSearch(data);
  });

}  

private performSearch(searchText) {
  console.log("Search: " + searchText);
  this.searchText = searchText;
  this.courseResults = this.rankAndFilter(this.courses, searchText).sortByDesc('rank'); 
  return this.courseResults;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-bszsae?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadd-rank.pipe.ts) with your suggestions but cannot get the desired output.  What am I doing incorrectly?  Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice your stackblitz until you pointed it out again here. Updated with suitable changes. Of course, will need finessing but this is the basic way it needs to be done for both performance and minimisation reasons (i.e move away from using pipes).

Comment: Could you share your forked link?  I looked more into filtering and ordering data in an angular application, and made modifications in moving the filtering logic into the component itself (as you suggest), but am having difficulties implementing the ordering logic.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is an [updated version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-bszsae?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the filtering but not the ordering.

Comment: @Matt I've provided StackBlitz forks for both the simple version and the one that uses debounce and distinctUntilChanged (also a global extension to Array).

Comment: BTW, any particular reason you're not searching the course_number as well?

Comment: Your help is very much appreciated!  And I planned to parse the digits from course_numbers and implement another filter to allow the user to filter courses based on numbers >= 100 and/or <100 and bind that logic to a couple of checkboxes in the view .