# how sort array with object by property use ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, ngfor

I neet to display in table sort data

**js**

```
let array = [
  { idx: number, name: string, btn: number, index: number },
  { idx: number, name: string, btn: number, index: number },
  { idx: number, name: string, btn: number, index: number }
]
```

**html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let ticket of array">
  <td>{{ ticket.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ ticket.btn }}</td>
  <td>{{ ticket.index }}</td>
<tr>
```

I need sort display by index value

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort)

Comment: You can create a pipe for sorting here is the link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882013/angular-2-sort-and-filter

Comment: it's better to sort in the component each time you get the data. you can as well write the sort pipe, but that's not something that is recommended by Angular team. (they haven't created it in the framework). https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: For that you have to create your own custom pipe. For further information, please refer [this discussion](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) and [Custom pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
let array = [
  { idx: 1, name: 'a', btn: 1, index: 2 },
  { idx: 2, name: 'b', btn: 2, index: 3 },
  { idx: 3, name: 'c', btn: 3, index: 1 }
];

// descending
let newarr = array.sort((a, b) => b.index - a.index);

//ascending
let newarr = array.sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index);

console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 7):

**Create a custom Angular pipe:**

Assumption: Suppose you have an array of objects with a field called 'order':

```
let items = [
   {name: 'item1', order: 2},
   {name: 'item2', order: 1}
];
```

**First**: Generate a pipe in terminal:

```
ng g p sortByOrder
```

**Second**: Modify the generated code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'sortByOrder'
})
export class SortByOrderPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[]): any[] {
    return value.sort((n1,n2) => 
    {
      return n1.order - n2.order; 
    });
  }
}
```

**Third**: Use in html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | sortByOrder" >
</div>
```

Comment: Shadi, I tried this solution with a date attribute. So I switched order with date. Didn't work. Is there something wrong with your SortByOrderPipe  function? I think so

Answer (score 3):

Here is OrderBy pipe library is available.
 https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe

```
 npm install ngx-order-pipe --save
```

Answer (score 3):

you should use a pipe to sort the data before the show in view:

```
<tr *ngFor="let ticket of array|sort-pipe">
   <td>{{ticket.name}}</td>
   <td>{{ticket.btn}}</td>
   <td>{{ticket.index}}</td>
<tr>
```

in sort pipe, you can use :

```
 array.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
   return obj1.idx > obj2.idx;
});
```

Comment: Anyone thinking of doing it this way should be aware that angular does NOT provide a sort pipe out-of-the-box for performance and magnification reasons - https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 0):

**You can just use sorting arrays:**

```
function sortFunc(a, b) {
  if ( a.index < b.index ){
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a.index > b.index ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

let array = [
  {idx: number, name: string, btn: number, index: number},
  {idx: number, name: string, btn: number, index: number},
  {idx: number, name: string, btn: number, index: number}
].sort(sortFunc);
```

**Or you can use lodash** `orderBy` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#orderBy